# Erro ao tentar criar uma Proc no banco

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Estou tentando rodar uma Stored Procedure no banco e está dando essa mensagem:

> Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner,
>   information_schema, sys, or yourself

Como eu resolvo isso?

Se a Proc já existe e eu apenas altero, eu rodo. Só não consigo rodar uma nova.

Eu fiz esse select:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER');
GO
```

E recebi isso:

> server;;CONNECT SQL
>
> server;;VIEW ANY DATABASE

O que isso significa?

Comment: O que a Proc faz ? Altera alguma permissão ?

Comment: @Motta, olhando a `PROC` não vi nada que alterasse, de alguma forma, permissões. Existe no final da `PROC` um grant(`Grant Execute on SP_CMO_SEL_PORTARIA_OIT1980_INATIVOS to cmo`)

Comment: É este o problema , o user que roda a sp não tem grant para dar grant.

Comment: @Motta, nesse caso, qual seria a solução? Eu preciso rodar a proc em ambiente de desenv, pois ela existe apenas no ambiente de produção.

Comment: Rodei sem o grant e funcionou, mas deveria ter o grant, mas vou deixar isso para os que vierem depois. Esse é um projeto de apenas 5 dias e não tenho tempo para entender nada.

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo as orientações do Motta, o qual atribuo a ele a resolução do meu problema, fiz o seguinte para solucionar. Comentei o `GRANT` no final da `PROC` e rodei a `PROC` em ambiente de desenvolvimento. Isso resolveu o meu problema.

Comment: Mas por que o grant existia ?

Comment: @Motta, não sei. Apenas cheguei aqui para fazer algumas correções num período de 5 dias. Sei que o ambiente de desenv aqui não está configurado corretamente e estou tendo vários problemas, como o VB 6 que não roda e etc... Mas para isso somos chamados, para corrigir.

Comment: Funcionou deixa quieto ...